# Display page content according button click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I display page content according to the button I click?
I would like that on entering the page it presents the HTML of a button, but if you click on the other button the page loads another HTML.

I made a very simple example, and I would like the page to load the html inside the container class and then click on another button to load the content of the container-fluid class.
Sorry if I was confused.

Thanks!

**My simple example**

```
  <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="Grelha">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/button/128/Button-Close-icon.png" style="width:30px; height:30px; cursor:pointer" >
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="Vquadrado">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/button/128/Button-Play-icon.png" style="width:30px; height:30px cursor:pointer"> 
          </a>
        </li>

   <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center text-lg-left tab-pane">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
            <img class="Images" src="https://source.unsplash.com/pWkk7iiCoDM/400x300" alt="">
            <div class="ImageText"> Name</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
            <img class="Images" src="https://source.unsplash.com/aob0ukAYfuI/400x300" alt="">
            <div class="ImageText"> Name</div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap" style="margin-left: 3px;">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <a>
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485963631004-f2f00b1d6606?auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80" class="img-fluid Vimages"> 
              <div class="VimageText"> Name1</div>
            </a> 
              <a>         
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502865787650-3f8318917153?auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" class="img-fluid Vimages">
              <div class="VimageText"> Name1</div>
            </a>
          </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to recreate a tabs/pagination type thing or are you trying to add/remove whole chunks of html? Are they separate html files? Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: I think it's tabs / pagination

Comment: @ChrisW. ... For what I want to do, this is usually used <a data-toggle="tab">
class = "tab-pane fade in active"> ... but couldn't implement -.- sorry if I expressed myself badly

Comment: Looks like you're already using bootstrap, are you just trying to implement their [tabs nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabs)?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle container with all styles which makes it visible or not.

For example:

```
display:none;
visibility: hidden;
```

```js
const button1 = document.querySelector('.toggle-first');
const button2 = document.querySelector('.toggle-second');
const firstContainer = document.querySelector('.first');
const secondContainer = document.querySelector('.second');



button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  firstContainer.style.display = 'block'; // Or visibility: visible or other style
  
  secondContainer.style.display = 'none';
});


button2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  secondContainer.style.display = 'block'; // Or visibility: visible or other style
  
  firstContainer.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<div class="container first">
  <h1> First container </h1>
</div>

<button class="toggle-first"> Toggle first container </button>

<div class="container second">
  <h1> Second container </h1>
</div>

<button class="toggle-second"> Toggle second contianer </button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me! However that is not what I want. This is usually used ` <a data-toggle="tab">
class = "tab-pane fade in active">` ... but couldn't implement -.- sorry if I expressed myself badly

Comment: Do you want to hide the first container and show second container-fluid?

Comment: No, I want the first container associated with button 1 to be active, but when I click button 2, container 1 is "hidden" and button 2 content is displayed

Comment: That's exactly what is does @John

Comment: @ГлебКлецков 
at first it is showing the first container and the second container, is it possible to display only the first container? The second container will only be displayed when you click the button.

Comment: @John If add display:none; to style of the second container it will be hidden by default

Comment: Now I understand everything, thank you very much for your help and explanation! best regards

Comment: @John I liked helping you!